# Parameters for configuring the decoder in pocketsphinx

Tags: cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I began to study the pocketsphinx.
I have a list of possible parameters for configuring the decoder. But there is no explanation of which parameter is responsible for which configuring. In the [tutorial CMUSphinx](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/pocketsphinxhandhelds/)  there is only a small part of them. This is not enough for me. Somebody has materials, which explains what parameter is responsible for which configuring. I will be very grateful for the help!

```
[NAME]      [DEFLT]     [VALUE]
-agc        none        none
-agcthresh  2.0     2.000000e+00
-alpha      0.97        9.700000e-01
-ascale     20.0        2.000000e+01
-aw     1       1
-backtrace  no      no
-beam       1e-48       1.000000e-48
-bestpath   yes     yes
-bestpathlw 9.5     9.500000e+00
-bghist     no      no
-ceplen     13      13
-cmn        current     current
-cmninit    8.0     8.0
-compallsen no      no
-debug              0
-dict               
-dictcase   no      no
-dither     no      no
-doublebw   no      no
-ds     1       1
-fdict              
-feat       1s_c_d_dd   1s_c_d_dd
-featparams         
-fillprob   1e-8        1.000000e-08
-frate      100     100
-fsg                
-fsgusealtpron  yes     yes
-fsgusefiller   yes     yes
-fwdflat    yes     yes
-fwdflatbeam    1e-64       1.000000e-64
-fwdflatefwid   4       4
-fwdflatlw  8.5     8.500000e+00
-fwdflatsfwin   25      25
-fwdflatwbeam   7e-29       7.000000e-29
-fwdtree    yes     yes
-hmm                
-input_endian   little      little
-jsgf               
-kdmaxbbi   -1      -1
-kdmaxdepth 0       0
-kdtree             
-latsize    5000        5000
-lda                
-ldadim     0       0
-lextreedump    0       0
-lifter     0       0
-lm             
-lmctl              
-lmname     default     default
-logbase    1.0001      1.000100e+00
-logfn              
-logspec    no      no
-lowerf     133.33334   1.333333e+02
-lpbeam     1e-40       1.000000e-40
-lponlybeam 7e-29       7.000000e-29
-lw     6.5     6.500000e+00
-maxhmmpf   -1      -1
-maxnewoov  20      20
-maxwpf     -1      -1
-mdef               
-mean               
-mfclogdir          
-min_endfr  0       0
-mixw               
-mixwfloor  0.0000001   1.000000e-07
-mllr               
-mmap       yes     yes
-ncep       13      13
-nfft       512     512
-nfilt      40      40
-nwpen      1.0     1.000000e+00
-pbeam      1e-48       1.000000e-48
-pip        1.0     1.000000e+00
-pl_beam    1e-10       1.000000e-10
-pl_pbeam   1e-5        1.000000e-05
-pl_window  0       0
-rawlogdir          
-remove_dc  no      no
-round_filters  yes     yes
-samprate   16000       1.600000e+04
-seed       -1      -1
-sendump            
-senlogdir          
-senmgau            
-silprob    0.005       5.000000e-03
-smoothspec no      no
-svspec             
-tmat               
-tmatfloor  0.0001      1.000000e-04
-topn       4       4
-topn_beam  0       0
-toprule            
-transform  legacy      legacy
-unit_area  yes     yes
-upperf     6855.4976   6.855498e+03
-usewdphones    no      no
-uw     1.0     1.000000e+00
-var                
-varfloor   0.0001      1.000000e-04
-varnorm    no      no
-verbose    no      no
-warp_params            
-warp_type  inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wbeam      7e-29       7.000000e-29
-wip        0.65        6.500000e-01
-wlen       0.025625    2.562500e-02
```

Answer (score 3):

Type `pocketsphinx_continuous` on command line and you will get all parameter list along with their default value and description.

like this:

```
Arguments list definition:
[NAME]                  [DEFLT]         [DESCR]
-adcdev                                 Name of audio device to use for input.
-agc                    none            Automatic gain control for c0 ('max', 'emax', 'noise', or 'none')
-agcthresh              2.0             Initial threshold for automatic gain control
-allphone                               Perform phoneme decoding with phonetic lm
-allphone_ci            yes             Perform phoneme decoding with phonetic lm and context-independent units only
-alpha                  0.97            Preemphasis parameter
-argfile                                Argument file giving extra arguments.
-ascale                 20.0            Inverse of acoustic model scale for confidence score calculation
```

...

Comment: In which directory should I enter a command `pocketsphinx_continuous` to view the list?

Comment: If you install pocketsphinx and set the env path to binaries and libs as per the install instructions then you can use pocketsphinx_continuous command from any directory.

https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx/

Comment: Thank you so much. I figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

No need to install pocket-sphinx.

The whole list is in the source repo:
https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/blob/master/doc/pocketsphinx_continuous.1

Answer (score 1):

Also I'd like to add that short description of parameters are not quite easy since most of them are parameters of the complex algorithms used in speech recognition like gaussian selection or trellis search. If you are interested in details, you'd better read more about algorithms. A good source is a thesis by Dr. Mosur K. Ravishankar:

[Efficient Algorithms for Speech recognition](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.72.3560)